# BodyCodec and pipe method forward status code

Tags: vert.x

I would like to ask about error handling for streaming with body codec and pipe method.

I am having GateWay and Storage services communicating via HTTP.

A user can send GET request to GateWay which forwards the request to Storage service which responses with the required file.

The problem is when the file is not found. In this case, the user receives a response with status 200 and status message OK.

It seems that response with status 404 is never received by the GateWay Service (or at least not before the response is already sent) but the HttpServerRequest response is ended with status 200.

Is there any way that the GateWay service forwards the status code from the Storage service response to user ????

Thank you

GateWay Service:

```java
httpClientRequest.as(BodyCodec.pipe(request.response().setChunked(true))).rxSend()
    .subscribe(
        response -> {
            if (response.statusCode() != OK_STATUS) {
                routingContext.response().setStatusCode(response.statusCode()).end();
            }
        },
        error -> LOG.error("KO")
    );
```

Storage Service:

```java
var options = new OpenOptions().setRead(true).setCreate(false).setWrite(false);

request.pause();

fileSystem
    .rxOpen("pathToFile", options)
    .flatMapCompletable(asyncFile -> asyncFile.rxPipeTo(request.response()))
    .subscribe(
        () -> LOG.info("OK"),
        error -> {
              request.resume();
              routingContext.response()
                            .setStatusCode(404)
                            .setStatusMessage("File not found")
                            .end();
       }
    );
```

[Communication schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELCGe.png)

Comment: Can you update the snippet to show which file options you use to open the file? I believe by default it's created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, by default a file is created if doesn't exist. But I don't want that a file is created if does not exist, I just want to send http response with status 404 and then the GateWay should forward it to the user. My options are : new OpenOptions().setRead(true).setCreate(false).setWrite(false); Thank you

Comment: Can you check the file actually doesn't exist? I just tried the snippet and got `io.vertx.core.file.FileSystemException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Comment: I am sure the file does not exist, I am also having the java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException. 
Please have a look at [communication schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELCGe.png). 

I think that the problem is the following:
In case of an error, the response to request B has an empty body (with status 404) so the BodyCodec thinks that the pipe is successfully closed so it responses to the request A with status 200 instead of waiting for the response and forwarding the correct status code. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I believe I got it know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebClient` pushes response bytes to the body codec before the `Single` returned by `rxSend` completes. This is by design, as the `WebClient` only operates by buffering content before handing it over to the user.

For your use case, it would be better to work with the raw `HttpClient`.

```
request.response().setChunked(true);
HttpClientRequest httpClientRequest = httpClient.get(port, host, requestURI);

httpClientRequest
  .handler(httpClientResponse -> {
    if (httpClientResponse.statusCode() != OK_STATUS) {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(httpClientResponse.statusCode()).end();
    } else {
      httpClientResponse.pipeTo(request.response(), ar -> {
        if (ar.failed()) {
          LOG.error("KO");
        }
      });
    }
  }).exceptionHandler(t -> handleConnectionFailure(t)).end();
```